# Windows RDP, do I need file and print sharing running?

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp

Before I lock myself out, does file and print sharing need to be installed on the nic for RDP to work properly. If not, why would you have if on a public facing nic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Before I lock myself out, does file and print sharing need to be installed on the nic for RDP to work properly.

No. RDP uses TCP port 3389, as such it uses TCP/IP not File & Print Sharing.

> If not, why would you have if on a public facing nic?

You shouldn't need to have it on. If your firewall is configured properly to block SMB it is not a problem *at this point in time*.

Comment: To add, you wouldn't lock yourself out at all by just testing it.  You would just have to try to make the connection and see if a login prompt appears.